# Convert column in dataframe to percentile rank - Python 3.x

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a `Pandas` dataframe which looks like this:

```
| id | name |         time        |
|:--:|:----:|:-------------------:|
|  1 | eric | 2014-05-16 15:15:11 |
|  2 | eric |  2014-05-27 3:43:43 |
|  3 | eric | 2014-04-24 13:25:20 |
|  4 | tony | 2014-04-19 20:18:58 |
|  5 | tony |  2014-05-08 17:8:5  |
|  6 | tony | 2014-05-21 16:55:44 |
|  7 | eric |  2014-05-18 11:26:3 |
|  8 | eric | 2014-04-05 17:51:53 |
|  9 | tony | 2014-04-06 14:21:39 |
| 10 | tony | 2014-05-08 22:24:27 |
| 11 | tony |  2014-04-10 23:11:2 |
| 12 |  zac | 2014-05-04 13:13:44 |
| 13 | eric |  2014-04-03 6:50:1  |
| 14 | eric |  2014-04-25 6:22:39 |
| 15 | tony |  2014-04-14 0:23:55 |
| 16 |  zac | 2014-04-19 12:12:54 |
| 17 |  zac |  2014-05-30 1:36:15 |
```

What I am looking to do is to replace the values in the `time` column with a percentile rank of the **time of day**. I need to convert this `datetime` object into a percentile rank.

In Oracle SQL, I could do:

```
SELECT id, name, FLOOR( (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TO_CHAR(time, 'hh24:mm:ss')) -1) * 10 / COUNT(*) OVER ()) AS "Rank"
```

Desired output would look something like:

```
| ID | THE_NAME | Rank |
|:--:|:--------:|:----:|
| 15 |   tony   |   0  |
| 17 |    zac   |   0  |
|  2 |   eric   |   1  |
| 13 |   eric   |   1  |
| 14 |   eric   |   2  |
|  7 |   eric   |   2  |
| 16 |    zac   |   3  |
|  3 |   eric   |   4  |
| 12 |    zac   |   4  |
|  9 |   tony   |   5  |
|  1 |   eric   |   5  |
|  6 |   tony   |   6  |
|  8 |   eric   |   7  |
|  5 |   tony   |   7  |
|  4 |   tony   |   8  |
| 10 |   tony   |   8  |
| 11 |   tony   |   9  |
```

And, for reference, here is an [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa54b/2)

I have not found *any* reference on Stack Overflow for this type of question, which is why I do not have a current attempt to show where it is failing.

**NOTE:** I see Pandas has a [`rank` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) but I do not understand how to use it on a `datetime` type where I need to extract only 24hr time

Attempting @PrinceFrancis solution:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df = df.sort_values(['time']).reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)
total_size = len(df.index)
df['Rank'] = df.index * 10 / total_size
print(df)
```

Yields:

```
    name      time      Rank
0   tony  00:23:55  0.000000
1    zac  01:36:15  0.588235
2   eric  03:43:43  1.176471
3   eric  06:22:39  1.764706
4   eric  06:50:01  2.352941
5   eric  11:26:03  2.941176
6    zac  12:12:54  3.529412
7    zac  13:13:44  4.117647
8   eric  13:25:20  4.705882
9   tony  14:21:39  5.294118
10  eric  15:15:11  5.882353
11  tony  16:55:44  6.470588
12  tony  17:08:05  7.058824
13  eric  17:51:53  7.647059
14  tony  20:18:58  8.235294
15  tony  22:24:27  8.823529
16  tony  23:11:02  9.411765
```

When trying to cast to int via:
`df['Rank'] = int(df.index * 10 / total_size)`

It yields error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Float64Index'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the rank function, but you could get the result by applying the `rank formula` after re-indexing the dataframe as follows

```py
df['Rank'] = df.index * 10 / total_size
```

Complete example is as follows

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name' : ('eric','eric','eric','tony','tony','tony','eric','eric','tony','tony','tony','zac','eric','eric','tony','zac','zac'),
    'time' : [datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for d in ('2014-05-16 15:15:11','2014-05-27 3:43:43','2014-04-24 13:25:20','2014-04-19 20:18:58','2014-05-08 17:08:05','2014-05-21 16:55:44','2014-05-18 11:26:03','2014-04-05 17:51:53','2014-04-06 14:21:39','2014-05-08 22:24:27','2014-04-10 23:11:02','2014-05-04 13:13:44','2014-04-03 6:50:01','2014-04-25 6:22:39','2014-04-14 0:23:55','2014-04-19 12:12:54','2014-05-30 1:36:15')]
})
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df = df.sort_values(['time']).reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)
total_size = len(df.index)
df['Rank'] = df.index * 10 / total_size
df
```

Result is

```
    name    time    Rank
0   tony    00:23:55    0
1   zac     01:36:15    0
2   eric    03:43:43    1
3   eric    06:22:39    1
4   eric    06:50:01    2
5   eric    11:26:03    2
6   zac     12:12:54    3
7   zac     13:13:44    4
8   eric    13:25:20    4
9   tony    14:21:39    5
10  eric    15:15:11    5
11  tony    16:55:44    6
12  tony    17:08:05    7
13  eric    17:51:53    7
14  tony    20:18:58    8
15  tony    22:24:27    8
16  tony    23:11:02    9
```

Comment: Issue is, I am not getting the correct rank, I am getting a float. Casting to int yields: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Float64Index'`

Comment: I used the same dataframe from your sample, and I have got the Rank as integer. Can you share the code to create `df` with values? Also python and pandas versions that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** :
**Here solution for the problem depend on the solution that has been mentioned by Prince Francis**

Solution:-

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name' : ('eric','eric','eric','tony','tony','tony','eric','eric','tony','tony','tony','zac','eric','eric','tony','zac','zac'),
    'time' : [datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for d in ('2014-05-16 15:15:11','2014-05-27 3:43:43','2014-04-24 13:25:20','2014-04-19 20:18:58','2014-05-08 17:08:05','2014-05-21 16:55:44','2014-05-18 11:26:03','2014-04-05 17:51:53','2014-04-06 14:21:39','2014-05-08 22:24:27','2014-04-10 23:11:02','2014-05-04 13:13:44','2014-04-03 6:50:01','2014-04-25 6:22:39','2014-04-14 0:23:55','2014-04-19 12:12:54','2014-05-30 1:36:15')]
})
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df = df.sort_values(['time']).reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)
total_size = len(df.index)
df['Rank'] = df.index * 10 / total_size
```

Then you can casting use apply function in pandas

```
def casting(value):
    return int(value)

df['Rank'] = df['Rank'].apply(casting)

df
```

```
Out[1]: 
    name      time  Rank
0   tony  00:23:55     0
1    zac  01:36:15     0
2   eric  03:43:43     1
3   eric  06:22:39     1
4   eric  06:50:01     2
5   eric  11:26:03     2
6    zac  12:12:54     3
7    zac  13:13:44     4
8   eric  13:25:20     4
9   tony  14:21:39     5
10  eric  15:15:11     5
11  tony  16:55:44     6
12  tony  17:08:05     7
13  eric  17:51:53     7
14  tony  20:18:58     8
15  tony  22:24:27     8
16  tony  23:11:02     9
```

**Using Rank Function**

Rank function in pandas working like sort give ranke based on rank in sorted list here example.

```
df['Rank'] = df['time'].rank()
df = df.sort_values('Rank')
df
```

```
Out[2]: 
    name      time  Rank
0   tony  00:23:55   1.0
1    zac  01:36:15   2.0
2   eric  03:43:43   3.0
3   eric  06:22:39   4.0
4   eric  06:50:01   5.0
5   eric  11:26:03   6.0
6    zac  12:12:54   7.0
7    zac  13:13:44   8.0
8   eric  13:25:20   9.0
9   tony  14:21:39  10.0
10  eric  15:15:11  11.0
11  tony  16:55:44  12.0
12  tony  17:08:05  13.0
13  eric  17:51:53  14.0
14  tony  20:18:58  15.0
15  tony  22:24:27  16.0
16  tony  23:11:02  17.0
```

Comment: I appreciate you trying to use random data, but I don't understand how to use your solution with the example data I posted to achieve the desired result I posted.

Comment: you mention that facing casting problem so you can just make function and use apply function in your dataframe

Comment: The issue with casting is related to another answer below. Not the original problem of the question. There is a lot of code (`random_string`??) in your answer that makes it hard for an end user to implement your solution. Thank  you for the effort, though.